# Does gitlab provide API for exploring groups?

Tags: gitlab

In gitlab UI, you can "explore" groups and see all groups on the gitlab server.  Is there a corresponding API endpoint for listing out all publicly readable groups regardless of your ownership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only see your own groups unless you are an admin.

> Get a list of groups. (As user: my groups, as admin: all groups)

```
GET /groups
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Foobar Group",
    "path": "foo-bar",
    "description": "An interesting group"
  }
]
```

Here is the official [API documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html)